# Material not rendering properly in blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files

So I am trying to render a simple glass cube using a tutorial from youtube. I did exactly as shown in the video but i am not getting the desired image 
[image: this is what i get][image: i want]

Comment: actually I dont see the problem. Your render is just from another perspective and other color, but still correct, isnt it? Edit your answer and describe exactly whats wrong with your render.

Answer (score 2):

Material is rendered properly.Its your nodes that need to be configured properly in order to match the one in tutorial, and your lighting setup doesn't seem to match the one in tutorial, along with perspective.